# My event handler stripper code isn't working

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I found a method here on stack overflow that strips all event handlers from a given event. However, when I copied the code into my program it gave me a "Reference not set to an instance" error.

Here is the code in question:

```
        FieldInfo f1 = typeof(Control).GetField("DocumentCompleted",
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        object obj = f1.GetValue(browser);
        PropertyInfo pi = browser.GetType().GetProperty("Events",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        EventHandlerList list = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(browser, null);
        list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
```

The error happened on this line:

```
object obj = f1.GetValue(browser);
```

The browser object is an instance of WebBrowser, and it has been instantized at this point.

---

Edit: Came up with a different way of removing the handlers.

Comment: The error would indicate that it's `f1` that's not been set.

Comment: try this `FieldInfo f1 = typeof(Control).GetField("DocumentCompleted")`. remove BindingFlags

Comment: Still null, it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocumentCompleted is a public event, not a private static field, so f1 is null and cause your error

Comment: I tried "FieldInfo f1 = typeof(Control).GetField("DocumentCompleted", BindingFlags.Public);"

But f1 was still null.

Comment: use GetEvent("DocumentCompleted", BindingFlags.Public)